# Execute xkill in i3

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, i3

I'm trying to bind [`xkill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xkill) to a key combination like this:

```
bindsym $mod+Pause exec xkill
```

but nothing happens after I press the keys.

xkill works ok if I execute it from launcher.

I tried redirecting stderr to a file, but the file is empty after executing xkill.

Any ideas how to use `xkill` with keyboard shortcuts in *i3*?

Comment: I have this same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xkill is unable to run because the keyboard is still grabbed. `bindsym --release $mod+Pause exec xkill` should do the trick.

[From the i3 User's Guide](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#keybindings):

> Some tools (such as import or xdotool) might be unable to run upon a KeyPress event, because the keyboard/pointer is still grabbed. For these situations, the --release flag can be used, which will execute the command after the keys have been released.

Comment: thanks, this is going to be useful if I ever use i3 again :) used it for about a year, but it works lousy with projectors...